# How to get the list of objects with its corresponding name rather than the index number?

Tags: r, list, lapply

I'd like to know if there would be a way to get the corresponding `indexing` `name` in a `list` ?

as example :

```
lapply(list(mtcars, airquality), dim )
[[1]]
[1] 32 11

[[2]]
[1] 153   6
```

I would like to get

```
mtcars
[1] 32 11

airquality
[1] 153   6
```

Comment: `setNames(object = lapply(list(mtcars, airquality), dim ), nm = c("mtcars", "airquality"))`

Comment: It's as simple as starting with a named list `list(mtcars=mtcars, airquality=airquality)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `mget` to return the value of string objects in a `list` and this will also `name` the `list` elements

```
lapply(mget(c("mtcars", "airquality")), dim)
#$mtcars
#[1] 32 11

#$airquality
#[1] 153   6
```

If the data is not already loaded i.e. by calling

```
data(mtcars)
data(airquality)
```

then, we specify `inherits = TRUE` in `mget`

```
lapply(mget(c("mtcars", "airquality"), inherits = TRUE), dim)
```

Comment: When I run your code i get the following errors: `Error: value for ‘mtcars’ not found`

Comment: @Daniel I think you didn't load the data using `data(mtcars)`.  One option is `inherits = TRUE`